# Receiving error from task generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication after Gradle upgrade

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have upgrade to Gradle 8.0.2.  With the upgrade I was require to add plugin 'maven-publish'.  I also added the java plugin.  I am receiving the below error.  I can recreate this locally.  Going through several other questions, I have created the below publish.  If I run 'gradle --stacktrace --info publishToMavenLocal', 2 things stand out to me.  1) After failure, I see "Caching disabled for task ':generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication' ..." and 2) In the stacktrace, I see "caused by ... UncheckedIOException: Could not write to file '...\build\publicaitons-\mavenJ.ava\pom-default.xml' ...".  I have spent a day googling all this with little help.  My company does not allow me to copy/pasted into stackoverflow.  So I can not provide my full build.gradle.  Any assitence would be grateful.

**Error**
Execution failed for task ':generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication'.
could not apply withXML() to generate POM
java.lang.NullPointer (no error message)

```
pubishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from(componenets.java)
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest taking your Gradle file, and remove any parts that are specific to your company and post that. It is really difficult to help you with such little information.

Comment: `from(componenets.java)` typo